# Decompress a string with more nested strings

Tags: java, string, compression

The assignment consists in decompress a string. In particular, the code has to work for 3 samples as illustrated in the picture. [image: Input - Output]

My code here works in the first 2 of the samples. However, I am not able to come up with the 3rd sample. Probably I did not understand probably the concept of recursion. Can you help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Compression4 {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input=in.next();
    System.out.println(uncompress(input));

}
public static boolean flag = true;

public static String uncompress(String compressedText)
{   
    return uncompress(compressedText, "", "");
}
public static String getMultiple(String x, int N) {
    if (N == 0) return "";

    return ""+x+getMultiple(x,N-1);
}
public static String uncompress(String text, String count, String output)
{   
    if (text.equals("")) 
    {
        return output;
    }
    if(text.charAt(0) == '(')
     {       
         int FirstIndex = text.indexOf("(")+1;
         String inner = text.substring(FirstIndex, text.lastIndexOf(")"));
         //System.out.println(inner);
         flag = false;
         return uncompress (inner, count, output);

     }
    else if (Character.isLetter(text.charAt(0))) 
    {
        //letter case - need to take the count we have accrued, parse it into an integer and add to output
        if (flag==true)
        {
                //System.out.println(count);// * text.charAt(0);

                String s = String.valueOf(text.charAt(0));
                output += getMultiple(s,Integer.parseInt(count));                           
                count ="1";
        }         
        else
        {
            //System.out.println(count);// * text.charAt(0);
            output += getMultiple(text,Integer.parseInt(count));
            //System.out.println("output: "+output);
            count="0";
        }

    }

    else if(Character.isDigit(text.charAt(0))) 
    {
        //digit case - need to add to the count but keep as a string because must be parsed later
        if(flag)
            count += (""+text.charAt(0));
        else
        {
            count = "0";
            count += (""+text.charAt(0));

        }

    }

    //parse the *remainder* of the string, one character at a time, so pass in the substring(1)

    return uncompress(text.substring(1), count, output);

        }
}
```

Comment: It's a good assignment! But the only specification you have are the three samples?

Comment: I will add some more instructions

Comment: As can be understood from these examples, we assume that the number 11 in the string 11ab indicates that the next symbol a be repeated 11 times. If we want a longer pattern to be repeated use parentheses: number 4 in the string4(ab) indicates that the substring ab be repeated 4 times. All uncompressed strings are only made up of the two symbols a and b. While the compressed strings also can contain numbers and parentheses as in the examples above.

Comment: Good Leonardo. But now you should be more specific on what is not clear about recursion. At the moment your question seems something like "here is my not working code, please let it works". As moderators usually suggest add your clarification in the question not in the comments.

Comment: Another suggestion: here the problem is more related to parsing than to decompression. What the assignment asks is to think how to write an executor of "a string rendering language" :). So you have to parse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Overview_of_process.

Comment: I don't know how to apply recursion when there are more nested strings. This code works for the first two samples but not for the third because my problem is exactly recursion. I don't think there is a problem of parsing

Comment: Oh no it's not a problem of parsing. I mean that you have to think to the problem as a parsing problem. You can find some examples about language parsing that could help to solve your assignment.

Comment: I would think regex would get you farther than checking individual characters. You just need to know your groupings. 1) A letter, 2) A number followed by a letter, 3) A number followed by a group. Case 1, leave alone, case 2, do the expansion, and else case 3, you recurse on the group.

Comment: @cricket_007 I think a regex would be difficult since he will have to parse nested parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the long code but it's more easy to explain with code than with words.

Premise:

- I think to the problem as an interpreter of a language to render a string
- the language is simple and functional so recursive interpretation is possible

Algorithm phases:

- First: tokenize the expression (to work at an higher level of abstraction)
- Second: parse the expression just tokenized

Recursion: the logic is based on the syntax of the language. Key concepts of a recursion:

- the base cases and the recursive cases
- the state necessary to a single recursion (local variables of recursion, those passed as parameters to the recursive method)
- the state for the all recursion (global variables of recursion, those read/write in some specific recursion)

I've made many comments to explain what the algorithm is doing. If it's not clear I can explain it better.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestStringDecompression {

    // simpleExpr examples: a | b | 123a | 123b | 123(a) | 123(ab) | 123(ba) | (ab) | (ba)
    // 11ab = aaaaaaaaaaab = = expression = simpleExpr simpleExpr = 11a b
    // 4(ab) = abababab = expression = simpleExpr = 4(ab)
    // 2(3b3(ab)) = bbbabababbbbababab = expression = compositeExpr = 2 ( simpleExpr simpleExpr ) = 2 ( 3b 3(ab) )

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new StringInflater().inflate("11ab"));
        System.out.println(new StringInflater().inflate("4(ab)"));
        System.out.println(new StringInflater().inflate("2(3b3(ab))"));
    }

    public static class StringInflater {

        // This store the position of the last parsed token
        private int posLastParsedToken = 0;

        public String inflate(String expression) {
            return parse(tokenize(expression), 0, false);
        }

        /**
         * Language tokens:
         * <ul>
         * <li>literals:
         * <ul>
         * <li>intLiteral = [0-9]*</li>
         * <li>charLiteral = [ab]</li>
         * </ul>
         * </li>
         * <li>separators:
         * <ul>
         * <li>leftParen = '('</li>
         * <li>rightParen = ')'</li>
         * </ul>
         * </li>
         * </ul>
         */
        private Object[] tokenize(String expression) {
            List<Object> tokens = new ArrayList<Object>();
            int i = 0;
            while (i < expression.length()) {
                if ('0' <= expression.charAt(i) && expression.charAt(i) <= '9') {
                    String number = "";
                    while ('0' <= expression.charAt(i) && expression.charAt(i) <= '9' && i < expression.length()) {
                        number += expression.charAt(i++);
                    }
                    tokens.add(Integer.valueOf(number));
                } else {
                    tokens.add(expression.charAt(i++));
                }
            }
            return tokens.toArray(new Object[tokens.size()]);
        }

        /**
         * Language syntax:
         * <ul>
         * <li>simpleExpr = [intLiteral] charLiteral | [intLiteral] leftParen charLiteral+ rightParen</li>
         * <li>compositeExpr = [intLiteral] leftParen (simpleExpr | compositeExpr)+ rightParen</li>
         * <li>expression = (simpleExpr | compositeExpr)+</li>
         * </ul>
         */
        private String parse(Object[] tokens, int pos, boolean nested) {
            posLastParsedToken = pos;
            String result = "";
            if (tokens[pos] instanceof Integer) {
                /** it's a intLiteral */
                // get quantifier value
                int repetition = (int) tokens[pos];
                // lookahead for (
                if (tokens[pos + 1].equals("(")) {
                    // composite repetition, it could be:
                    // simpleExpr: "[intLiteral] leftParen charLiteral+ rightParen"
                    // compositeExpr: "[intLiteral] leftParen (simpleExpr | compositeExpr)+ rightParen"
                    result = parse(tokens, pos + 1, true);
                } else {
                    // simple repetition, it could be:
                    // simpleExpr: [intLiteral] charLiteral
                    result = parse(tokens, pos + 1, false);
                }
                result = repeat(result, repetition);
                // evaluate the rest of the expression because syntax allows it
                if (posLastParsedToken + 1 == tokens.length) {
                    // end of the expression
                    return result;
                } else {
                    // there are other simpleExpr or compositeExpr to parse
                    return result + parse(tokens, posLastParsedToken + 1, false);
                }
            } else if (tokens[pos].equals('(')) {
                /** it's a leftParen */
                // an open paren means what follow this token is considered nested (useful for string to treat as char sequence)
                return parse(tokens, pos + 1, true);
            } else if (tokens[pos].equals(')')) {
                /** it's a rightParen */
                // a closed paren, nothing to render
                return "";
            } else {
                /** it's a charLiteral */
                if (nested) {
                    // it's nested between paren, so more parsing is requested to consume next charLiteral or next simpleExpr or compositeExpr
                    return tokens[pos] + parse(tokens, pos + 1, nested);
                } else {
                    // it's not nested between paren, return charLiteral as is
                    return "" + tokens[pos];
                }
            }
        }

        private String repeat(String s, int repetition) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < repetition; i++) {
                result.append(s);
            }
            return result.toString();
        }

    }

}
```